# Replace the NaNs in pandas dataframe with empty_rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, nan

I have the following table (df):

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | finished | 1234 |
| A2 | ongoing | 1235 |
| A3 | NaN | 1236 |
| A4 | finished | 1237 |
| A5 | started | 1238 |
| A6 | NaN | 1239 |

I would like to replace the NaNs in the dataframe with empty_row. How do I do that?

**Desired output:**

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | finished | 1234 |
| A2 | ongoing | 1235 |
| A3 | empty_row | 1236 |
| A4 | finished | 1237 |
| A5 | started | 1238 |
| A6 | empty_row | 1239 |

What I tried so far?

```
if df['col2'] == 'NaN':
   df['col2'] = 'empty_row'
```

I get the following error: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `fillna` method https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].fillna('empty_row')
```